# Watched app make Lubuntu 18.04 stuck

Tags: lubuntu, chmod, appimage

I tried installing watched app (download from [here](https://www.watched.com/download))

I ran below code:

```
chmod +x WATCHED-1.0.8.AppImage
./WATCHED-1.0.8.AppImage
```

When the app appears, my Lubuntu 18.04 LTS stuck and I don't know why. Can anyone help me resolving this?

Comment: Do you see anything in the system logs that might explain the problem? Does the CPU hit 100% and stay there? More information is needed to help you solve this problem.

Comment: @Matigo when i ran `./WATCHED-1.0.8.AppImage`, the system has been stucked and i can't open the terminal or task manager